# Issue in accessing one site from another site through limited access URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, cross-domain, forms-authentication

I have two websites, both in separate domains. So for e.g. http://example1.com and http://example2.com. Both sites are in ASP .NET and use Forms authentication. Users of example1.com need to access certain resources of example2.com without needing to have accounts in example2.com. So whenever a user of example1.com needs to access a resource in example2.com, a temporary URL is generated through which the user can access the resource. The URL is a limited period one time use URL that is invalidated after first time use. Here is how it works.

1. When example1.com needs to access resource on example2.com side, a response.redirect occurs with an encrypted token in the query string. e.g. http://example2.com/path/resource1/?token=*encryptedToken*
2. This token is read on example2.com side and if it is valid, forms authentication is set to "temp user". "Temp User" is a limited access user created specifically as a proxy for example.com users.

Below is the code to achieve this in Application_AuthenticateRequest event

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    const string TempUser = "TempUser";
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {                
        var url = Request.Url;              
        var token = Request.QueryString["token"];

        if(IsKnownUrl(url) && IsValidToken(token))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(TempUser, false);
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
    }
}

private bool IsKnownUrl(string url){

    //Logic to check the url is from known sources
}

private bool IsValidToken(string token){

    //Logic to token is valid and not expired
}
```

This was working fine until both sites were switched to SSL. i.e. https://example1.com and https://example2.com. and this stopped working. The Response.Redirect from example1.com to example2.com goes into a 302 loop, which means for some reason the authentication cookie is not being set or accepted. When I view the network activity in Chrome Browser Developer tools, I see following trail

**Name                                                             Status**

https://example2.com/path/resource1/?token=*encryptedToken*      302

https://example2.com/path/resource1/?token=*encryptedToken*      302

https://example2.com/path/resource1/?token=*encryptedToken*      302

..................

Finally the Browser gives up and indicates the page is redirecting too many times.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you checked out what's happening using Fiddler, for instance are the cookies being set? (If you don't know what Fiddler is, it's a reverse proxy, it logs the raw http requests and responses made from your system, the headers, body, everything). 

Also, you've probably done this already but just double check all your url references have also been updated to HTTPS, and that the cookie you are setting has the Secure property set to true (this setting shouldn't make a difference but just try it anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Aydin for your tip. For anyone who is also facing similar issue, here is the solution.

- After checking with Fiddler, I found that Authentication cookies (.ASPXAUTH) were being sent from the server but the browser was not sending them on subsequent requests.
- Also, the URLs from example2.com were being displayed in example1.com inside an IFrame. After some searching I found that for IFrames, the browser will send cookies only if **"SameSite=None"** is specified in the Set-Cookie response header.

So in the end I had to update my code to create the ASPXAUTH cookie manually since the cookie created by FormsAuthentication class sets its to "Lax".